# How to transform "sequence" data to "from & to" in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this dataset.

```
data.frame(
id = c("id1","id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id2"),
seq = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3),
obj = c("A","B","C","D","B","D","E")
)

   id seq obj
1 id1   1   A
2 id1   2   B
3 id1   3   C
4 id1   4   D
5 id2   1   B
6 id2   2   D
7 id2   3   E
```

I want to transform seq&obj variable , from to form.
like this.

```
data.frame(
  id = c("id1","id1","id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id2","id2"),
  from = c("start","A","B","C","D","start","B","D","E"),
  to = c("A","B","C","D","end","B","D","E","end")
)

   id  from  to
1 id1 start   A
2 id1     A   B
3 id1     B   C
4 id1     C   D
5 id1     D end
6 id2 start   B
7 id2     B   D
8 id2     D   E
9 id2     E end
```

If we think of id as a runner names , we can imagine that it passes through checkpoints named obj in the order of seq.

do you know any idea?
thank you.

Comment: You are just shifting the column and adding "start" and "end" at the start and end, respectively. I'm sure there is some tidyverse function for this. However, why are you doing this? Are you sure it wouldn't be better to use package igraph and create a graph?

Comment: thnk you Mr.Roland. I tried shift. but I don't know how to each id group. I want to try to use plotly sanky diagram.(but Your comment has made me curious about igraph as well.) @Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(seq) %>%
    summarize(from = c('start', obj), to = c(obj, 'end'), .groups = 'drop')
```

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  id    from  to
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 id1   start A
2 id1   A     B
3 id1   B     C
4 id1   C     D
5 id1   D     end
6 id2   start B
7 id2   B     D
8 id2   D     E
9 id2   E     end
```

If your initial data is already in the correct order (as in your given example), the `arrange()` call is unnecessary. However, with tabular data it’s best not to assume a specific order.